# Docker container to serve Laravel in a browser

Tags: docker

I'm attempting to spin up a docker container for a laravel app:-

**Edit**

**Dockerfile.nginx**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./nginx/my-site-config.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**nginx/my-site-config.conf**

```
server {
 listen       8027;
 server_name  localhost;

 # handle .php
 location ~ \.php$ {
    # 404
    try_files                     $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    # default fastcgi_params
    include                       fastcgi_params;

    # fastcgi settings
    fastcgi_pass                  php-fpm-container:9000;
    fastcgi_index                 index.php;
    fastcgi_buffers               8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size           32k;

    # fastcgi params
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT   $realpath_root;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=$base/:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp/";
 }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
#Nginx Service <-- doesn't work
 #  webserver:
 #    build:
 #      context: .
 #      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
 #    container_name: webserver
 #    restart: unless-stopped
 #    tty: true
 #    ports:
 #      - "8027:80"
 #      - "443:443"
 #    networks:
 #      - app-network

# works
webserver:
 image: nginx:alpine
 container_name: webserver
 restart: unless-stopped
 tty: true
 ports:
  - "8027:80"
  - "443:443"
 networks:
  - app-network
```

The commented-out code fails to launch with:-

[image]

Using the un-commented code and `nginx:alpine` as an image - the server hosts the nginx splash screen. There is a problem with my `Dockerfile.nginx` it appears.

Comment: You are using the `php:7-fpm` Docker image and that does not appear to have anything listening on port 80 to be forwarded to `localhost:8638`.  It looks like `php-fpm` from that image runs on port 9000 by default.

Comment: So what's the solution. Use a docker image which handles alternative port numbers?

Comment: You have only stated that you wanted to run Laravel inside Docker.  That will require at least `php`.  If you are planning on serving the Laravel application to web browsers, you would also need a web server.  If I were doing this, I would likely have one Docker image for `php-fpm` on port 9000 and another Docker image with a web server on port 80 and link them together.  You could then forward port 80 on the web server to `localhost:8638`.

Comment: Please see my edits. It's still not serving Laravel?

Comment: You need to make sure that nginx will forward the request for *.php to php-fpm, can you pull the nginx.conf and conf.d/* config content and add them to the question please?

Comment: @Rabin - Do you mean from inside the container: `$ docker exec -it 22982cc3ee07 /bin/bash` ?

Comment: I tried all these from within the container:-`$ cd /usr/local/nginx/conf
No such file or directory
$ cd /etc/nginx - No such file or directory
$ cd /usr/local/etc/nginx - No such file or directory`. Is this something to do with my `Dockerfile` config?

Comment: I was just thinking, you don't mean `nginx.conf` from my local filesystem do you?

Comment: @cookie in the container you should check the config under "/etc/nginx/" (this is the default path for nginx config file) there should be a nginx.conf file and probably "conf.d" or another folder which the "nginx.conf" reference to include files from.

Comment: @Rabin hmm, Within the container - I did try that: `cd /etc/nginx - No such file or directory`

Comment: I'll try the command you supplied as soon as i get a chance, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you `nginx:alpine` config for nginx

```
docker run -it --rm nginx:alpine /bin/sh
/ # cd /etc/nginx
/etc/nginx # ls -l
total 44
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            24 Dec 17 15:01 conf.d
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1077 Dec 15 14:55 fastcgi.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1007 Dec 15 14:55 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2837 Dec 15 14:55 koi-utf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2223 Dec 15 14:55 koi-win
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5231 Dec 15 14:55 mime.types
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Dec 17 15:01 modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           646 Dec 15 14:55 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           636 Dec 15 14:55 scgi_params
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           664 Dec 15 14:55 uwsgi_params
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3610 Dec 15 14:55 win-utf
```

This is the default nginx.conf

```
/etc/nginx # cat nginx.conf 

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And inside `conf.d` folder, there is a default server config

```
/etc/nginx # ls -l conf.d/
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1093 Dec 15 14:55 default.conf
```

which have a very basic server section

```
/etc/nginx # grep -vE " *#|^ *$" conf.d/default.conf 
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

As you can see it's only configure to server static content and there is no section to forward request to `*.php` to the php-fpm backed.

Usually you will need to replace this file (or if you need more control, overwrite `nginx.conf` all together).

At the minimum you need a section in the server config to redirect request to PHP to the backend.

```
    # handle .php
    location ~ \.php$ {
# 404
try_files                     $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# default fastcgi_params
include                       fastcgi_params;

# fastcgi settings
fastcgi_pass                  php-fpm-container:9000; # <--- this is the PHP-FPM container
fastcgi_index                 index.php;
fastcgi_buffers               8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size           32k;

# fastcgi params
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT   $realpath_root;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=$base/:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp/";
    }
```

You can use the site [NGINX Configuration Tool from DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx) to help you with creating a good starting point overall conf for your application, which you can then overwrite in the `nginx:apline` container.

Please note that both the nginx container and the the php container need to have access to your PHP application files.

## EDIT1

Customize the nginx image

```
FROM nginx:alpine

# If you have a bundle of config created by DO config file, 
# you can copy them all to overwrite all the settings.
# or use
# to overwrite a single file
# COPY my-site-config.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Update your docker-compose to use your customized version of the nginx image

```
version: '3'
services:

 #PHP Service
 app:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: digitalocean.com/php
  container_name: app
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  environment:
    SERVICE_NAME: app
    SERVICE_TAGS: dev
  working_dir: /var/www
  networks:
   - app-network

 #Nginx Service
 webserver:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
  container_name: webserver
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  ports:
   - "8027:80"
   - "443:443"
  networks:
   - app-network
```

## EDIT2

Seems you are missing some key parts of how Docker works and how to work with multi-container environment, for starter, I suggest you start with a working template like this [one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose) (read all the page to understand the meaning of the bind mount point) as you can see both the `app` (PHP container) and the `webserver` have access to the files via bind mounts, and this template also give you the option to overwrite the php configuration and the nginx without building a new container.

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_mysql_root_password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: How do I edit the `default.conf` within the running container? I'm attempting:- `COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` within my `Dockerfile` but cant see the updates when I'm inside container? Further, the splash page persists. I'm a total novice with docker. Thanks.

Comment: Based on docker-compose file content you are adding/COPY the file to the wrong image (php-fpm), you need to add it to the nginx image (nginx:alpine), create another file called e.g Dockerfile.nginx and add your customization there. See my edit's in the answer

Comment: Are you able to advise on my latest edit above? The webserver fails to start completely now.

Comment: you need to have 2 containers, one for the nginx and the 2nd for php-fpm process, and you need to have the same name in the config, so in the above example if we set the php-fpm container as "php-fpm-container" this is the name of the container.
Also, you can use "Laravel sail" to run your laravel code in dev

Comment: See my EDIT2 section @cookie